# Jenkins multibranch pipeline with Jenkinsfile from different repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Git repository with code I'd like to build but I'm not "allowed" to add a `Jenkinsfile` in its root (it is a Debian package so I can't add files to upstream source). Is there a way to store the `Jenkinsfile` in one repository and have it build code from another repository? Since my code repository has several branches to build (one for each Debian release) this should be a multibranch pipeline. Commits in either the code or `Jenkinsfile` repositories should trigger a build.

**Bonus complexity:** I have several code/packaging repositories like this and I'd like to reuse the same `Jenkinsfile` for all of them. Thus it should somehow dynamically fetch the right Git URL to use. The branches to build have the same names across all repositories.

Comment: Do this option available in new versions or still same situation?

Comment: So, very old thread, but a way to accomplish this would be with git sub-modules.  Make a repository you control, add a submodule for the debian package and a submodule for the shared jenkinsfile.  When your repository is checked out, the two other git repositories will be present as subdirectories.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer is : you **cannot** do that with a `multibranch pipeline`. Multibranch pipelines are only designed (at least for now) to execute a specific pipeline in `Pipeline script from SCM` style, with a fixed `Jenkinsfile` at the root of the project.

You can however use the [Multi-Branch Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) plugin made for multibranch **freestyle** projects. First, you need to define your `multibranch freestyle configuration` just like you would with a `multibranch pipeline configuration`.
Select this new item like shown below :

[image: New Freestyle multi-branch project]

This type of configuration will behave exactly same as the `multibranch pipeline` type, i.e. it will create you a folder with the name of your configuration and a sub-project for each branch it automatically detected.

The implementation should then be a piece of cake :

1. Specify your `SCM` repository in the multibranch configuration
2. Call another build as part of your build/post-build as you would do in a standard freestyle project, except that you have to call a parameterized job (let's call it `build-job`) and give it your repository information, i.e. Git URL and current branch (you can use the pre-defined variables `$GIT_URL` and `$GIT_BRANCH` for this purpose)
3. In your `build-job`, just define either an inline pipeline or a pipeline script checked out from SCM, and inside this script do a SCM checkout and go on with the steps you need to build. Example of `build-job` pipeline content :

.

```java
node() {
  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/${GIT_BRANCH}']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '${GIT_URL}']]]

  stage 'Build'
  // Build steps...
}
```

Of course if your different multibranches projects need to be treated a bit differently, you could also use intermediate projects (let's say `build-project-A`, `build-project-B`, ...) that would in turn call the generic `build-job` pipeline)

The one, major drawback of this solution is that you will only have one job responsible for all of your builds, making it harder to debug. You would still have your multibranch projects going blue/red in case of success/error but you will have to go back to called `build-job` to find the real problem of your build.

Comment: That freestyle multibranch option seems now officially deprecated. Jenkins _does not_ presently offer an option to do multibranch builds for projects where Jenkinsfile is not present, at all. Which really sucks

Answer (score 13):

The best way I have found is to use the Remote Jenkinsfile Provider plugin. https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/

This will add an option "by Remote Jenkinsfile Provider plugin" under Build Configuration>Mode then you can point to another repo where the Jenkinsfile is. I find this to be a much better solution than the Pipeline Multibranch Defaults Plugin, which makes you store the Jenkins file in Jenkins itself, rather than in source control.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

U can make use of this plugin 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-multibranch-defaults-plugin/blob/master/README.md
Where we need to configure the jenkinsfile on jenkins rather than having it on each branch of your repo

Answer (score 0):

I have version 2.121 and you can do this two ways:

**Way 1**

In the multibranch pipeline configuration > Build Configuration > Mode > Select "Custom Script" and put in "Marker File" below the name of a file you will use to identify branches that you want to have builds for.

Then, below that in Pipeline > Definition select "Pipeline Script from SCM" and enter the "SCM" information for how to find the "Jenkinsfile" that holds the script you want to run. It can be in the same repo you are finding branches in to create the jobs (if you put in the same GitHub repo's info) but I can't find a way to indicate that you just use the same branch for the file.

**Way 2**

Same as above, in the multibranch pipeline configuration > Build Configuration > Mode > Select "Custom Script" and put in "Marker File" below the name of a file you will use to identify branches that you want to have builds for.

Then, below that in Pipeline > Definition select "Pipeline Script" and put a bit of Groovy in the text box to load whatever you want or to run some script that already got loaded into the workspace.

Comment: What version of Pipeline plugin are you using? Latest is 2.6 and it does not have "Custom Script" option.

Comment: The only place I've found this mentioned is in [Cloudbees docs](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/workflow/#pipeline-custom-factories), so I'm guessing it's coming from some paid plugin. Who knows!

Comment: Link by @ZombieDev seems out of date; I think [this part](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines-user-guide/pipeline-as-code) is what he was referring to.

Comment: Note: This is available on Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise only not in vanilla Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i have an escenario whith a gitlab project based on gradle who has dependencies on another gitlab preject based on gradle too (same dashboard, but differents commits, differents developers).

I have added the following lines into my Jenkinsfile (the one which depends)

```
stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                git branch: 'dev', credentialsId: 'jenkins-generated-ssh-key', url: 'git@gitlab.project.com:root/coreProject.git'
                sh './gradlew clean'  
            }                 
        }
```

Note: Be awark on the order on the sentences.
If you have doubt on how to create jenkins-generated-ssh-key please ask me