# Jenkins: force all projects to use the same jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to configure Jenkins to always run using a predefined Jenkinsfile for all projects, rather than pulling a Jenkinsfile from the project repo?  The goal here is to make sure that a certain set of stages are always being run.  If we allow projects to define their own Jenkinsfile, they could theoretically just skip some required stages in their project (like unit testing).

I want to make sure this never happens, but simply telling everyone "don't remove these stages from your Jenkinsfile" seems a bit brittle.

Comment: Do you create all the pipelines centrally? You could just paste that specific Jenkinsfile into the "Pipeline script" option when creating them, rather than using "Pipeline script from SCM".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins multibranch pipeline with Jenkinsfile from different repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041342/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-with-jenkinsfile-from-different-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Shared Library and define all of the stages and steps there. Then the Jenkinsfile in the SCM for each application needs only to point to the shared library and run a method. You can also pre-define variables specific to each application in the Jenkinsfile before you call the shared library.

This won't FORCE the application use your code--they can simply rewrite the entire Jenkinsfile, but at least they don't have control of the code you wrote and they can't simply comment out or easily add stages.