# Jenkins Multi-Branch: Use Jenkinsfile from different repo

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I use the Multi-Branch project to automatically discover new branches and create jobs for them. Yet, these branches should not provide their own Jenkinsfiles.  Instead, the Jenkinsfile should be loaded from another git repo.

Unfortunately, the `Build Configuration` section of the Multi-Branch configuration page only offers the possibility to load the Jenkinsfile from the branch that is built. Is there a plugin to add further options to checkout the Jenkinsfile from another repo?

The motivation is the following. If the branch developers can add their own Jenkinsfiles, they can do whatever they want, e.g. corrupt delete other projects in the workspace or access push secrets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins multibranch pipeline with Jenkinsfile from different repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041342/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-with-jenkinsfile-from-different-repository)